# What is the difference between layout_constraintStart_toEndOf and layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to konw the difference between layout_constraintStart_toEndOf and layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf.Maybe you can show a example.

Answer (score 3):

[RTL (Right to Left)](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) layout compatibility, where Start is actually on the right, and End is on the left.

Answer (score 2):

There is a special way for RTL languages:

in Persian, Arabic and other RTL (right-to-left) Languages, `end` is `left` and `start` is `right` for English and other LTR (left-to-right) Languages we just use left and right.

This difference actually about has the best compatibility with device language that could be one of the RTL or LTR languages.

Android will decide on your device language show your elements in which position.